# Wordpress custom theme & content call

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a `get_header()` option for getting content from a wordpress page, to insert in a bootstrap designed theme?

I have tried `get_content()` but this seems to not work, probably due to calling functions, but I cannot find this anywhere online.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the_content() will used where you want to display the contents not in the function.php

Comment: if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  
  the_content();
  
 } 
}

Comment: you can put this code into page.php and index.php or any custom templates.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a play later when i am home. Appreciate it thank you.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes :-( general question... and helpful answer.

Comment: does this only work for one website? i have made another site today using the same "template" but its not working even though the whole thing is replicated, but in a different domain folder?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `the_content();` function for getting content from wordpress page

Comment: Is there any function.php calls i need to insert? or just straigh the_content()? appreciate it. will try when im back.

Comment: no you just need to use the_content(); in while loop of  page where you want to display content from wordpress page or post